# Can I set Internet usage quota in squid on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: internet, squid, quota

I want to set Internet usage quota in squid on Ubuntu 12.04.
Please suggest me the squid policy for set Internet usage quotas.

Thanks in advance
Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

[This how-to](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Bandwidth-Limiting-HOWTO) has fairly detailed instructions on setting up bandwidth limit pools in squidproxy.

You could also go the route of a 3rd-party solution, like [Squid Quota](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/squidquota/).

Comment: It will be really nice if you construct the answer and add necessary points here while placing the source links to where you referred to. Refer [**How do I write a good answer?**](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @AzkerM I always try to provide enough relevant detail to answer the question asked. In this case, it is a pretty basic how-to question with little implementation detail. What else do you think this answer could include, other than pasting the content I linked?